# pandas, expand series of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, concatenation

I have a series that looks like this:

```
     result
3    pd.DataFrame({"ABC":1,"American":2,"Heroes":3})
8    pd.DataFrame({"ABC":1,"American":2,"Heroes":3})
11   pd.DataFrame({"ABC":1,"American":2,"Heroes":3})
14   pd.DataFrame({"ABC":1,"American":2,"Heroes":3})
17   pd.DataFrame({"ABC":1,"American":2,"Heroes":3})
20   pd.DataFrame({"ABC":1,"American":2,"Heroes":3})
```

How do I produce this result:

```
     ABC    American    Heroes
3    1      2           3
8    1      2           3
11   1      2           3
14   1      2           3
17   1      2           3
20   1      2           3
```

This is driving me crazy, cuz if concat I loose my index.

here's my closest try `pd.concat(myDf.tolist(), axis=1)`

Comment: this is nice; a dataframe in a series; akin to R's list columns. curious how u got to this point tho

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? There has to be a better way, right?

Comment: I just posted the entire script I'm working on here:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/237944/script-for-matching-regex-matches-between-two-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty convoluted structure, I tried reconstructing your series of dataframes this way (I don't see any series with this structure in the link you point to):

```
df_list = [pd.DataFrame({"ABC":[1],"American":[2],"Heroes":[3]}),
           pd.DataFrame({"ABC":[1],"American":[2],"Heroes":[3]}),
           pd.DataFrame({"ABC":[1],"American":[2],"Heroes":[3]})]

series = pd.Series(df_list)
```

And to get what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(series\
                      .apply(lambda x : x.squeeze().to_list())\
                      .to_list(),
                  columns=series[0].columns)
```

Results:

```
    ABC American    Heroes
0   1   2           3
1   1   2           3
2   1   2           3
```

Comment: In the link I posted variable `t` ends up being a Series full of DataFrames. I'm out of time but I will test your solution asap in the morning.